# No route found when I set a parameter

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm developing an app with Symfony 4 but I'm having a little problem here.

I made a controller with a required parameter but when I to follow the route I get this message:

[image]

Here's the code of is my html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Registro Madre{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Ingrese los datos de la madre</h1>
    <form action="/insertMadre" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombres:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="apellido">Apellidos:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" class="form-control" id="apellido" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                    <input type="date" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nacionalidad">Nacionalidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contacto">Teléfono de Contacto</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="contacto" id="contacto" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dui">DUI (sin guiones)/No. Pasaporte</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dui" id="dui" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="departamento">Departamento:</label>
                    <select name="departamento" id="departamento" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Seleccione una opción..</option>
                        {% for departamento in departamentos %}
                            <option value="{{ departamento.id }}">{{ departamento.depname }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="municipio">Municipio:</label>
                    <select name="municipio" id="municipio" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Seleccione una opción..</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <legend>Datos Clínicos</legend>
        <div id="datos-clinicos">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">Fórmula Obstétrica</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">G</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="formG" id="formG">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">P</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="formP" id="formP">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">P</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="formP1" id="formP1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">A</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="formA" id="formA">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="datos-clinicos-text">V</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="formV" id="formV">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="enfermedadMedica">Enfermedades médicas que afecten el desarrollo del embarazo</label>
                    <select name="enfermedadMedica" id="enfermedadMedica" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Elija una opción</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="enfermedadExantematica">Enfermedad exantemática durante el embarazo</label>
                    <select name="enfermedadExantematica" id="enfermedadExantematica" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Elija una opción</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="informacionExtra">Otra Información</label>
                        <textarea name="informacionExtra" id="informacionExtra" class="form-control" rows="5" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn-site">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use App\Entity\Madre;
use App\Entity\DatosClinicosMadre;
use App\Entity\ProductoObstetrico;
use App\Entity\CondicionProducto;

class ProductoController extends AbstractController
{
    public function registro($id)
    {
        $madre = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Madre::class)->find($id);
        return $this->render('producto/register.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And here's my route:

```
registro-producto:
  path: /ingresar-producto/{id}
  name_prefix: nuevoProducto
  controller: App\Controller\ProductoController::registro
```

If I don't send a parameter I don't have any problems but when I want to send an ID it comes the issue, and if I set the route with a parameter and I don't send a parameter I get an error telling me that I must have to send a parameter. I don't know what's going on...

**UPDATE**

This is what I get when I run php bin/console debug:router

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: I've added your configuration to a fresh project, and I'm not seeing any error. Can you run `php bin/console debug:router` and show us the output?

Comment: @maiorano84 Hi! I've updated the output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't declared the param type.

Try amending your routes file to this:

```
registro-producto:
  path: /ingresar-producto/{id}
  name_prefix: nuevoProducto
  controller: App\Controller\ProductoController::registro
  requirements:
      id: \d+
```

Doing this will set the `{id}` type to *digit*, allowing the `/3` param.

See here:

Taken from Symfony Docs:

> Adding {wildcard} Requirements
>   
>   Imagine the blog_list route will contain a paginated list of blog posts, with URLs like /blog/2 and /blog/3 for pages 2 and 3. If you change the route's path to /blog/{page}, you'll have a problem:

```
blog_list: /blog/{page} will match /blog/*;
blog_show: /blog/{slug} will also match /blog/*.
```

> When two routes match the same URL, the first route that's loaded wins. Unfortunately, that means that /blog/yay-routing will match the blog_list. No good!
>   
>   To fix this, add a requirement that the {page} wildcard can only match numbers (digits)

ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html